# can I call javascript of a website without opening in webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, urlconnection

Is it possible to call the JavaScript of a website **without opening it in webview**.
I am using `URLConnection` to get the html but I want **to click a link on host website that in turn call a JavaScript function** through Java code.

I want either to call JavaScript function or the link **on click of a button on activity**
webview.loadUrl("javascript:") is able to do it but only after opening in webview.

Comment: I think it's not possible. But you could size the webview to only a few pixels. Maybe positioning the webview under another view in a FrameLayout could work as well.

Comment: BTW I really hope that `webview.loadUrl("javascript:...")` is not possible in Android when WebView has loaded non-assets pages, because this would have really great impact on security.

Comment: @hgoebl i tried it with a page in assets folder...shocked to know what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is impossible in current Android. In 4.5 there will be some script-engine to execute js or other scripts. BTw, why do you need this - to get content after click on content? seems strange..

Comment: my scenario is something like this: say stackoverflow login button might have been calling a javascript for authentication purpose and I want to make an app(without webview) with login button that could call the stackoverflow's login button in background for login

Comment: Wrong logic. But anyway if you need this and your site doesnt have any API to Log-in try to debug NET-tab in developer tools in browser and see what exact request to server goes(what URL, other data) and try to repeat them in your application.